# Import from Wolfram Mathematica: Purpose of \pmb and \noindent?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The code below was created from Mathematica software:

```
%% AMS-LaTeX Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

\title{Me Salva! ITD07}
\author{Leandro Carvalho}
\date{21/06/2017}
\maketitle{Estudo}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\text{r1}=\sqrt{18};\text{r2}=6\text{Cos}[\theta ];}\\
\pmb{\text{g1}=\text{PolarPlot}[\text{r1},\{\theta ,0,2 \pi \}];}\\
\pmb{\text{g2}=\text{PolarPlot}[\text{r2},\{\theta ,0,2 \pi \}];}\\
\pmb{\text{Show}[\{\text{g1},\text{g2}\}]}\\
\pmb{}\\
\pmb{\text{RegionPlot}\left[x^2+y^2<18,\{x,0,10\},\{y,0,10\},\text{PlotStyle}\to \text{Yellow}\right]}\\
\pmb{\text{RegionPlot}\left[(x-3)^2+y^2<9,\{x,0,10\},\{y,0,10\},\text{PlotStyle}\to \text{Blue}\right]}\\
\pmb{\text{RegionPlot}\left[x^2+y^2<18\&\&(x-3)^2+y^2<9,\{x,0,10\},\{y,0,10\}\right]}\\
\pmb{}\\
\pmb{\mathcal{R}=\text{ImplicitRegion}\left[x^2+y^2<18\&\&(x-3)^2+y^2<9,\{x,y\}\right];}\\
\pmb{\text{RegionDimension}[\mathcal{R}]}\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(2\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(\pmb{\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\int _0^{\sqrt{18}}5 r^3 \text{Sin}[\theta ] \text{Cos}[\theta ]drd\theta +\int _{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi
}{2}}\int _0^{6 \text{Cos}[\theta ]}5 r^3 \text{Sin}[\theta ] \text{Cos}[\theta ]drd\theta }\)
\end{doublespace}

\begin{doublespace}
\noindent\(135\)
\end{doublespace}

\end{document}
```

**The `pmb` and `noindent` commands are for what?**

Comment: `\pmb` is `Poor Man's Bold`,  for fonts  which do not have a bold version (usually bold version of math symbols, viz a bold version of `\mathbb`. `\noindent` suppresses the indentation of the next paragraph.

Comment: I think it's a very poor way to distinguishing between input and output. Difficult to conceive a worse method.

Comment: @egreg I agree with you. I found it very bad the output that the Mathematica software compiles

Comment: And doublespace also does not help much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**pmb**

DESCRIPTION
\pmb command turns on poor man's bold. It works by duplicating its argument slightly offset, giving a bold effect (at least in the horizontal direction); doesn't work well for horizontal lines, like - or +.

**EXAMPLE**

```
a \pmb a \boldsymbol a
```

[image: aaaa]

```
\pmb{a+b-c}\ \ a+b-c
```

[image: imagem2]

**noindent**

When used at the beginning of the paragraph, it suppresses the paragraph indentation. It has no effect when used in the middle of a paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

The usage of `\pmb` is simply absurd and likewise `doublespace`.

Some editing is needed if you want an acceptable result.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newcommand{\opn}{\operatorname} % shorthand
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\title{Me Salva! ITD07}
\author{Leandro Carvalho}
\date{21/06/2017}
\maketitle

\boldmath
\begin{align*}
& r_1=\sqrt{18};r_2=6\opn{Cos}[\theta ];\\
& g_1=\opn{PolarPlot}[r_1,\{\theta ,0,2 \pi \}];\\
& g_2=\opn{PolarPlot}[r_2,\{\theta ,0,2 \pi \}];\\
& \opn{Show}[\{g_1,g_2\}]\\[2ex]
& \opn{RegionPlot}[x^2+y^2<18,\{x,0,10\},\{y,0,10\},\opn{PlotStyle}\to \opn{Yellow}\\
& \opn{RegionPlot}[(x-3)^2+y^2<9,\{x,0,10\},\{y,0,10\},\opn{PlotStyle}\to \opn{Blue}\\
& \opn{RegionPlot}[x^2+y^2<18\&\&(x-3)^2+y^2<9,\{x,0,10\},\{y,0,10\}\\[2ex]
& \mathcal{R}=\opn{ImplicitRegion}[x^2+y^2<18\&\&(x-3)^2+y^2<9,\{x,y\};\\
& \opn{RegionDimension}[\mathcal{R}]\\[2ex]
& \text{\unboldmath $2$}\\
& \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\int _0^{\sqrt{18}}5 r^3 \opn{Sin}[\theta ]
    \opn{Cos}[\theta ]\,dr\,d\theta +
  \int _{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^{6 \opn{Cos}[\theta ]}5 r^3 \opn{Sin}[\theta ]
    \opn{Cos}[\theta ]\,dr\,d\theta\\[2ex]
& \text{\unboldmath $135$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]